# Why does macOS say Carrot Weather needs Rosetta when opening WhatsApp?

Tags: ventura, rosetta-2

I'm setting up a new MBP 14" M2, freshly updated to macOS 13.2. I've installed a bunch of apps, including both Carrot Weather and WhatsApp, both from the App Store.

When I startup WhatsApp is says that CarrotWeather needs Rosetta. This seems a little bizarre. What am I doing wrong?

[Quick video of it](https://i.imgur.com/1NjTen1.mp4)

Comment: WhatsApp is Intel only - so you do need Rosetta

Comment: Yes, I understand that, it's just weird to see it reference the wrong application in the pop-up. Might just be a bug.